# Prometheus exporter - reading CSV file having data from the past day

Tags: python, prometheus, exporter

I am writing a Prometheus exporter which has to rad different CSV files. Each of them contains one entire day of data from the past (the goal is to have the exporter read a new CSV file each day. One CSV file is uploaded to the server each day, containing the data of the previous day.

IN the CSV file, I have the same metrics every 5 mns. e.g :

```
Date;Time;data
23.03.20;23:55:00;1
23.03.20;23:50:00;50
23.03.20;23:45:00;3
```

I struggle to add theses data in Prometheus properly.

```
class CSVCollector(object):
  def collect(self):
    # We list all the min files in the current directory
    list_min = glob.glob("min*.csv")
    metric = GaugeMetricFamily(
                'day_tests_seconds',
                'kw', labels=["jobname"])
    for min in list_min :
      with open(min) as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=';')
        line_count = 0
        for row in csv_reader:
            if line_count == 1:
                correct_date_format = row[0][:6] + "20" + row[0][6:]
                datetime_row = correct_date_format + ';' + row[1]
                timestamp = int(time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(datetime_row, "%d.%m.%Y;%H:%M:%S").timetuple()))
                metric.add_metric(str(line_count), int(row[4]), timestamp)
            line_count += 1
    yield metric   
     


if __name__ == '__main__':
  # Usage: json_exporter.py port endpoint
  start_http_server(int(sys.argv[1]))
  REGISTRY.register(CSVCollector())
  while True: time.sleep(1)
```

Prometheus just read the first line, add it as a metric and read exactly the same again each time he **scrapes** the exporter. What am I doing wrong ? I feel like this data should be a Jauge, as it goes up and down, but Prometheus seems that he doesn't want different data from the same Jauge in one **scrape**?

Answer (score 4):

The [page](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/pull/5887/files) introduces a way to import history data to Prometheus.

The .txt file is OpenMetrics format, and an example import command is: `tsdb import rrd_exported_data.txt /var/lib/prometheus/ --max-samples-in-mem=10000`.

Sample file `rrd_exported_data.txt` (`[metric]{[labels]} [number value] [timestamp ms]`):

```
collectd_df_complex{host="myserver.fqdn.com",df="var-log",dimension="free"} 5.8093906125e+10 1582226100000
collectd_varnish_derive{host="myserver.fqdn.com",varnish="request_rate",dimension="MAIN.client_req"} 2.3021666667e+01 1582226100000
collectd_df_complex{host="myserver.fqdn.com",df="var-log",dimension="free"} 5.8093906125e+10 1582226100000
collectd_load{host="myserver.fqdn.com",type="midterm"} 0.0155 1582226100000
```

Maybe you can execute the command in your python code.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another [PR](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/pull/8084) ([docs](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/pull/8230/files#diff-1e47e7218df597c79a882aa1c109e42c332234bd8c92e1c493a788f8f64bb328R146)) just been merged. Now prometheus supports backfilling out-of-box:

```
promtool tsdb create-blocks-from openmetrics <input file> [<output directory>]
```

Answer (score -1):

Prometheus doesn't support data importing (aka push model) - it supports only data scraping (aka pull model). See [this article](https://prometheus.io/blog/2016/07/23/pull-does-not-scale-or-does-it/) for details. Additionally to this, Prometheus doesn't support storing historical data (aka backfilling).

If you need importing historical CSV data to Prometheus-like system, then take a look at VictoriaMetrics - it [supports importing CSV data](https://victoriametrics.github.io/#how-to-import-csv-data) and it [supports data backfilling](https://victoriametrics.github.io/#backfilling).